# Redshift: experiencing slow query performance between 2 segments

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

We’re experiencing slow query performance on AWS Redshift. Frequently we see that queries can take ±12 seconds to run, but only very little time (<500ms) is spent actually executing the query (according to the AWS Redshift console for an individual query).

Querying from svl_compile  we can confirm that the query compilation plan is already compiled.

In svl_query_report we see a long time delay between the start times of 2 segments accounting for the majority of the run time, although the segments themselves all execute very quickly (milliseconds)

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of things that could be going on but I suspect network distribution is involved.  Check STL_DIST.

Another possibility is that Redshift broke the query up and a subquery is running during that window.  This can happen with very complex queries.  Review the plan and see if there are any references to computer generated table names (I think they begin with't' but this is just from memory).

Spilling to disk could be happening but this seems unlikely given what you have said so far.  Also queuing delays doesn't seem like a match.  Both are possible but not likely.

If you post more info about how the query is running things will narrow down.  Actual execution report, explain plan, and/or logging table info would help hone in on what is happening during this time window.

Comment: Hi Bill, I'm replying to your answer as I have a similar issue. The total duration of ingesting procedures increased suddenly, e.g.: the total execution time of the steps takes ~500ms, but the whole call takes 3-4s. The Planning phase is taking longer than before (as per "Database performance" chart in Redshift GUI). What I checked already: 1) no issue with network distribution, 2) lock issue - I cannot find any, 3) SVL_COMPILE shows compile=0. Ingestion for all tables is affected similarly, even for tables that are rarely accessed. Do you have any idea what else I could check? Thank you!

Comment: There are a number of places things can get slowed down.  Queuing in the WLM, impacts from other activity on the database, data return, but it sounds like you have already focused in on the scan step.  Is this correct?  If so then looking at stl_scan for per table and per slice information would be informative.  It may be best to post a specific question so that better data can be shared and any incorrect assumptions on my part clarified.

Comment: Thank you Bill! I was going to open a new thread, but the issue disappeared immediately after the scheduled reboot and patching! What a relief.